# If-None-Match header not accepted request header

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to understand how Etag works in Django. I added middleware in settings (`'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware'`) and this seems to work as it generates the Etag:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2018 16:58:30 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.0
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 1210
ETag: "060e28ac5f08d82ba0cd876a8af64e6d"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

However, when I put `If-None-Match: '*'` in the request header, I get the following error:

```
Request header field If-None-Match is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

And I notice the request method sent back in the response is `OPTIONS` and the rest of the headers look like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2018 17:00:26 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

So the question is how do I get `If-None-Match` to be an allowed header? I'm not sure if this is a server or client issue. I'm using Django/DRF/Vue for my stack and Axios for making http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the response contains various CORS headers, I believe you have already used `django-cors-headers`, you could adjust `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` with `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` config option, get more detail on [its doc](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#cors_allow_headers).

Comment: Thanks, that did it! At least, now I know how to use those headers properly. Wish it would solve all my caching problems, but it's a start.

Comment: @EvanZamir glad I could help!